# From Change Log Table to Status on a Given Day

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am trying to convert a change log table into a historical status table using BigQuery's Standard SQL.

The part giving me a hang up is how to select the most recent change log that is before the date to join on.

I had not encountered window functions or indexing during my college years, so I would appreciate guidance on how to apply those functions if they're part of the ideal solution.

Change_Logs table

```
   Update                   Key      Tostring
1  2019-01-30 17:57:51.910  PS-5864  To Do
2  2019-02-11 20:59:08.582  PS-5864  In Progress
3  2019-02-12 19:52:18.733  PS-5864  Done
4  2019-01-31 16:52:12.832  PS-4672  To Do
5  2019-02-11 14:11:13.442  PS-4672  In Progress
6  2019-02-12 04:22:33.111  PS-4672  Done
```

Dates table

```
   Date
1  2019-02-10
2  2019-02-11
3  2019-02-12
4  2019-02-13
```

Desired Result:

```
   Date                     Key      Status
1  2019-02-10 00:00:00.000  PS-5864  To Do
2  2019-02-10 00:00:00.000  PS-4672  To Do
3  2019-02-11 00:00:00.000  PS-5864  To Do
4  2019-02-11 00:00:00.000  PS-4672  To Do
5  2019-02-12 00:00:00.000  PS-5864  In Progress
6  2019-02-12 00:00:00.000  PS-4672  In Progress
7  2019-02-13 00:00:00.000  PS-5864  Done
8  2019-02-13 00:00:00.000  PS-4672  Done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT d.date, key, 
  ARRAY_AGG(status ORDER BY l.update DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] status
FROM `project.dataset.dates` d
JOIN `project.dataset.change_logs` l
ON DATE_DIFF(d.date, DATE(l.update), DAY) > 0
GROUP BY d.date, key
```

You can test, play with above using sample data from your question as in example below

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.change_logs` AS (
  SELECT DATETIME '2019-01-30 17:57:51.910' `update`, 'PS-5864' key, 'To Do' status UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-11 20:59:08.582', 'PS-5864', 'In Progress' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-12 19:52:18.733', 'PS-5864', 'Done' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-01-31 16:52:12.832', 'PS-4672', 'To Do' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-11 14:11:13.442', 'PS-4672', 'In Progress' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-12 04:22:33.111', 'PS-4672', 'Done' 
), `project.dataset.dates` AS (
  SELECT DATE '2019-02-10' `date` UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-11' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-12' UNION ALL
  SELECT '2019-02-13' 
)
SELECT d.date, key, 
  ARRAY_AGG(status ORDER BY l.update DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] status
FROM `project.dataset.dates` d
JOIN `project.dataset.change_logs` l
ON DATE_DIFF(d.date, DATE(l.update), DAY) > 0
GROUP BY d.date, key
-- ORDER BY d.date, key
```

with result

```
Row date        key     status   
1   2019-02-10  PS-4672 To Do    
2   2019-02-10  PS-5864 To Do    
3   2019-02-11  PS-4672 To Do    
4   2019-02-11  PS-5864 To Do    
5   2019-02-12  PS-4672 In Progress  
6   2019-02-12  PS-5864 In Progress  
7   2019-02-13  PS-4672 Done     
8   2019-02-13  PS-5864 Done
```

Comment: Thank you! Your formatting was very clear and easy to follow along. Your solution works very nicely.
To make sure I understand the principles at play here;
First, the ON DATE_DIFF() Joins change_logs on any date preceding the current date row for each date row.
The ARRAY_AGG function creates an array of the most recent status for each key.
My ordering may be wrong here, but I think I've understood what you've detailed here. Thank you!

Comment: sure, glad it worked for you.please also consider voting up the answer

Answer (score 1):

The key idea is to generate the rows with a `cross join`.  Then what you really want is `lag(. . . ignore nulls)` -- but not supported in BigQuery.

Instead, you can do some array manipulation:

```
select d.date, cl.key,
       array_agg(cl.status ignore nulls order by d.date desc limit 2)[ordinal(2)]
from dates d cross join
     (select distinct key from change_logs cl) k left join
     change_logs cl
     on date(cl.update) = d.date and cl.key = k.key;
```

EDIT:

The above is not quite correct, because we are missing dates that occur before the specified period.  I think the simplest method is to add them and then remove them:

```
select *
from (select d.date, cl.key,
             array_agg(cl.status ignore nulls order by d.date desc limit 2)[ordinal(2)]
      from (select d.date
            from dates d 
            union 
            select distinct date(cl.update)
            from change_logs
           ) d cross join
           (select distinct key from change_logs cl) k left join
           change_logs cl
           on date(cl.update) = d.date and cl.key = k.key
    )
where date in (select d.date from dates);
```